# Where to ask a question to get answers with personal opinions (on technical thematics)?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question with **technical and personal opinions** about how developers use to represent visually a piece of software (classes, dependencies, etc.), relying on UML, Mind-maps, white boards, etc; but Stack Overflow doesn't seem the best place to ask it, cause it won't be a specific technical question on a practical problem, but more a general discussion with subjectives ideas.

So where would be the best place to ask this kind of question?

Comment: If it's discussions and opinions you're after, I'm afraid you're more than likely out of luck within the network. The subject matter you talk about does hint at the Programmers SE, but then be sure it really fits their site. The way in which you currently phrase it doesn't seem appropriate for that site either.

Comment: Are opinions about practical methodologies, that can be standard or not. It about (technical and not) alternatives to UML, from the experience of professional developers.

Comment: I would point to [on discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980) from Meta.P.SE.  Subjective is ok, discussions are problematic.

Comment: I was more on subjective than discussion. I mean, something can be discussed in the comments. But I mainly want subjective/objective answers.

Comment: A personal blog, a forum (set up one of your own if one doesn't exist), twitter, mailing lists. These are all technologies that predated SE. Advantage: unbounded discussion. Disadvantage: often turn into cess pits of flamewars and infuriating bad behavior.